# To list files based on size in unix

Tags: unix

**GOAL : To fetch list of files occupying more space in unix**

using the below command

**ssh serverName du /folderName/* | grep -v 'cannot' | sort -nr | head -10**

Using sort -nr to consider as numeric and sort in reverse (To get files occupying more space)

Using the grep -v 'cannot' because there is no access to few folders and these lines must be ignored before sorting

Below is the sample output

```
624    /folder1/folder2/conf
16     /folder1/folder2/error/include
192    /folder1/folder2/error
284    /folder1/folder2/htdocs
264    /folder1/folder2/icons/small
du: cannot read directory `/folder1/folder2/file1': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `/folder1/folder2/file3': Permission denied
```

Facing issues with grep and sort commands, as the error messages are not getting filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect stderr to stdout using `2>&1` so that you can grep out the error messages. You should also escape the wildcard so that it gets expanded on the remote machine, not on the local one.

```
ssh serverName du /folderName/\* 2>&1 | grep -v 'cannot' | sort -nr | head -10
```

Comment: Or probably just close the stderr. We get no sortable information from that messages anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `grep` if you close stderr.

```
ssh serverName du /folderName/\* 2>&- | sort -nr | head -10
```

Note that the wildcard is escaped.